# ConcurrentModificationError when traversing a tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, tree, concurrentmodification

When traversing a tree structure recursively in order to calculate weights and volumes for an entire bill of materials, I run into a ConcurrentModificationException. My approach in pseudocode:

1. Query initialization: add root node to list of nodes and check if it has any childs.
2. Progress documentation: Flag the node as visited.
3. Query childs: Checking for child nodes and if present add to allNodes with a level up flag.
4. Recursive traversal: Recursively traverse list until no more child elements are found.

I have tried to use iterators to allow myself to expand that array of nodes but ran into the same problem. Slowly running out of ideas here I am grateful for any hint.

NOTE: please forgive me to paste my problem not stating all the context for better readability. Let me know if you need more info.

```
// Initialization
List<Node> allNodes = new ArrayList<>();
allNodes.add(new Node(input, input, 0, false)     // (1)
int counter = 0;

// Method call
getAllNodes(allNodes);

// Query parent for child elements
public void getAllNodes(List<Node> nodes){
    for (Node node : nodes) {   
        if (!node.isVisited()) {      // (2)
            node.setVisited(true);
            String parentId = node.getId();
            Product product = QueryUtil.getFirstByIdNo(ctx, parentId, Product.class);
            if (isComposite(product)) {
                Iterable<Product.Row> rows = product.table().getRows();   // (3)
                for (Product.Row row : rows) {
                    allNodes.add(new Node(parentId, row.getProductListElem().getIdno(), ++counter, false));
                    --counter;
                }
                ++counter;
               // Recursive query of all node elements
                getAllNodes(allNodes);        // (4)
            }
        } 
    }
}

//Node Bean with getters, setters, constructor, toString
@Data
class Node {
    String parent;
    String id; 
    int level;
    boolean visited;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to modify the list that you are iterating(reading) over. And this is not allowed in JAVA. [for more explanation check [here]](https://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception)

To avoid this you can either get an iterator for your list and then loop over it, but that does not seem like a very good option for the code you have posted above. Thus, I'll recommend using `List<Node> allNodes = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();` instead of `List<Node> allNodes = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ayush Sharma. I was aware of that cocurrency issue since I am adding new nodes while traversing the tree. The other solution I tried was having the child nodes saved in a separate list only adding them at the end. But it didn't work whereas your solution in contrast was quick and is working. Great help!

Comment: adding at the end probably didn't work for you 'cause you are doing recursion, so somewhere on the top (in stack trace [call trace]) it sill is in iteration mode.
(sorry for the lack of appropriate tech words).